# Changing Value of a ComboBox in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Listbox with a DataTemplate which includes a Combobox. I need to change the selectedItem/Index of a particular ComboBox. How would I access it?

**Additional Detail**

All the combobox have the same options. If a Combobox is set to the same value as another ComboBox then the Combobox that was set first should return to empty (which is the first item in my `cbxOptions` Dictionary that the ComboBoxes are Bound to).

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="lbxHeaderDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Item1}"></Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Item2}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**C#**
**Populate UI**

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in _loadedData.Columns)
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
              (dc.ColumnName, cbxOptions));
}
```

**Trying to wipe combobox**

This is where I would expect I could foreach through the Listbox, checking the controls for a match at which point I'd change it to blank. However my foreach just gives me back stupid Tuple...which is readonly but I don't think that'd update my ComboBox anyways.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cbxSelected = (ComboBox)sender;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(cbxSelected);
    Label currentLbl = null;
    foreach (object o in ((Grid)parent).Children)
    {
        if (o is Label)
        {
            currentLbl = (Label)o;
        }
    }

    string LblText = currentLbl.Content.ToString();
    string cbxValue = cbxSelected.SelectedValue.ToString();

    //HERE I want to iterate through the listbox controls, not the datasource
    foreach (Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>> l in lbxDatFields.Items)
    {
        //l.Item2 = "";
        if (l.Item1.EndsWith(cbxOptions[cbxValue]))
            l = new Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(l.Item1, "");
    }
}
```

I'm sure there must be a very simple way of accessing the control. Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if additional info is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly and concisely illustrates your question, it's not practical to try to address your current design. Based on the bit of code you did post, one can make some observations though:

- Since `Tuple<...>` is immutable, you can't modify the `Item2` property. You have to replace the entire `Tuple<...>` object with a new one.
- The code you posted shouldn't even compile, because you are trying to modify the `l` variable in the `foreach` loop.
- Even if you could, it wouldn't change the element in the list itself, just that particular variable.
- Not that you even want to change the element; it's the selection of the combo box that should change, not its `Item2` options.

The use of a dictionary object for the `ComboBox` items eludes me. Perhaps with a complete code example, it would be more clear.

All that said…

> How would I access it?

This question comes up only because you are misusing WPF to start with. You should not be manipulating the UI directly; instead, your UI state should be represented in view model data structures. Then the `ComboBox` selection would be bound to a view model property, and the answer to your question would be simply to look at that property.

It's hard to know for sure, given the lack of details, but it appears to me that you are trying to implement a scenario where you have a list of items, where each item has a selectable option, and you want those options to be mutually exclusive. That is, only one item at a time can have any given option.

Assuming that's the case, I will show an implementation that in my opinion is much better than the approach you are attempting to implement. That is, it uses the basic idea I've proposed above, where you start with the data models, and then work back to the UI from there. Doing it this way, the data models are very simple and easy to understand, and so is all of the implementation for the behavior you want.

It looks like this…

First, start with the basic per-item view model data structure:

```
class PropertyChangedExEventArgs<T> : PropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    public T OldValue { get; }

    public PropertyChangedExEventArgs(string propertyName, T oldValue)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
        OldValue = oldValue;
    }
}

class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _name, value); }
    }

    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _value, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
            new PropertyChangedExEventArgs<T>(propertyName, oldValue));
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The above class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly. In a real-world program, this implementation would typically be in a base class, which each view model class inherits. If you do a significant amount of WPF programming, you'll have this base class as a reusable component you just include in each project, either in a separate project you reference, or as a code snippet. There are many WPF user frameworks you can use as well, which provide this functionality.
- In this particular example, there's not already a convenient mechanism for event subscribers to know the old value of the property after it's changed, but the logic involved requires that, so that the key for the mapping from value to model object can be removed from the dictionary when it's no longer valid. There are a variety of ways to address that need — arguably, the more straightforward is to just do a linear search of the `Values` collection of the relatively small dictionary. But I decided to extend the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` class instead, as that's a more scalable solution to that particular need (and so is more useful as a *general* solution to the problem).

Here, I only need one class to implement that interface, and it's simpler for the sake of illustration to keep everything together there.

Okay, so with the per-item data structure in place, we also want a parent data structure to encapsulate these items as a collection and to handle the broader manipulation of these items:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
        {
            new ItemViewModel { Name = "Item #1" },
            new ItemViewModel { Name = "Item #2" },
            new ItemViewModel { Name = "Item #3" },
        };

    public IReadOnlyList<string> Options { get; } =
        new [] { "Option One", "Option Two", "Option Three" };

    private readonly Dictionary<string, ItemViewModel> _valueToModel =
        new Dictionary<string, ItemViewModel>();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        foreach (ItemViewModel itemModel in Items)
        {
            itemModel.PropertyChanged += _ItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void _ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ItemViewModel.Value))
        {
            ItemViewModel itemModel = (ItemViewModel)sender;
            PropertyChangedExEventArgs<string> exArgs =
                (PropertyChangedExEventArgs<string>)e;

            if (exArgs.OldValue != null)
            {
                _valueToModel.Remove(exArgs.OldValue);
            }

            if (itemModel.Value != null)
            {
                if (_valueToModel.TryGetValue(
                    itemModel.Value, out ItemViewModel otherModel))
                {
                    otherModel.Value = null;
                }

                _valueToModel[itemModel.Value] = itemModel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This object maintains the collection of items, as well as the collection of options for the `ComboBox` elements. This is also where the logic to handle the mutual-exclusion of options is handled, because this is the class that has access to all of the per-item data objects.

On that last point: you could, of course, provide a way for the per-item objects to interact with the parent data structure to be able to enumerate the other per-item objects. This would allow each per-item object to handle its own property changes, so that the parent object doesn't need to subscribe to each per-item object's `PropertyChanged` event. But doing so would also increase coupling between the classes and make the basic logic harder to follow. IMHO, it is preferable to keep this top-down approach, where owned objects know as little as possible about their owners (and in this case, nothing at all).

Note that with the above, all of the logic necessary to track the state of the items and ensure mutual exclusion of the options setting is present, without *anything* that is actually specific to the view objects. The above code would work in any program, with or without a user interface. It's completely decoupled from the view itself.

And so, how does the view use it? Like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO45196940ComboBoxExclusive.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO45196940ComboBoxExclusive"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ItemViewModel}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Options, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Similar to how the `ItemViewModel` object knows nothing about the `MainViewModel`, but rather the latter subscribes to the former's `PropertyChanged` event and accesses the item object's properties to do the work, the view binds to the relevant properties of both model objects, without those objects having any need to know about those bindings, or the view itself.

The view has no code-behind at all. It's just a simple, declarative description of what the user sees, and does nothing more than present to the user the current state of the underlying data.

Doing it this way keeps everything very simple and disconnected, so that each object has a very narrow set of responsibilities, and the interaction between objects is kept to a minimum. This makes it easier to assure that the code is correct, and reduces the mental workload when implementing features, because you're only dealing with a small section of the code at a time, instead of having to keep straight how everything relates to each other.

For what it's worth, it took *way* longer to explain the code above here in this post, than it did to write the code itself. Following the standard WPF idioms, the actual authoring the code can go very quickly, especially if you already have the basic base classes in place for things like `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Much of that time savings comes from not having to puzzle over how to get at the data you need. By following better practices, the data is always already right there where you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. I've been looking over your code and trying to get into the MVVM mindset. One quick question, how would one dynamically populate `Items`? Currently you have it populating on start up but if I need to add to `Items` I need the Bindings to refresh correct?

Comment: The example above uses `ObservableCollection<T>` as the collection source. It implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which means that WPF can observe changes to the collections and will automatically update whatever it's bound to. You can add, remove, or change items at any time, and the bound UI will be updated accordingly.

Comment: What I was actually looking for was `this.DataContext as MainViewModel` which allowed me to access `Items` so that I could interact with the data, thanks! Do you get an Null exception when you set a single combobox to Option One, then Option Two then back to Option One?

Comment: _"I was actually looking for was this.DataContext as MainViewModel"_ -- ah, yes. Very commonly, instead of declaring the view model in XAML, one will maintain a class field, so you have direct access instead of having to cast the `DataContext` value. I don't usually bother with that for simple examples like this, so casting is a fine alternative, especially if you don't have a lot of code that needs it. _"Do you get an Null exception"_ -- no exceptions should be thrown by the code above. It's valid for `SelectedItem` to be set to `null`; it just means nothing is selected.

Comment: While I really appreciate your answer and I think I'll get a lot more out of it in the long run I'm afraid I have to give the tick to mm8. He has answered the core question more directly.

Comment: You're free to choose whichever answer you like as the accepted one. I just want to make sure you understand that using his answer just perpetuates your own misuse of the WPF API. It's a very bad approach.

Comment: Also, copied the above code into a blank example and still getting a Null ref error on the line `_modelToValue[itemModel.Value] = itemModel;` for the example I listed above. I believe this is because on the line previous it has set itself to `Null`.

Comment: The fix for this is adding the line `if (itemModel.Name != otherModel.Name)` before setting `otherModel.value = null`.

Comment: Literally just created a solution, copied only your three sections of code and the Null ref exception happens when changing ComboBox 1 from Option 1 -> Option 2 -> Option 1

Comment: My apologies...you are right, that's a scenario my example doesn't handle correctly. However, IMHO it's also not correct to simply not set `otherModel.Value = null` if the model objects are the same, because that leaves the dictionary mapping value names to models in an inconsistent state. It's better to not have the dangling mapping left in the first place. Fixing that does require a little bit more work; see edit above, in which I've extended `PropertyChangedEventArgs` so that the event receiver has access to the old value, which is used to remove the now-unused key.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Listbox with a DataTemplate which includes a Combobox. I need to change the selectedItem/Index of a particular ComboBox. How would I access it?

By accessing the corresponding data item in the `Items` collection of the `ListBox`.

Replace your `Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` with a class that also includes a `SelectedIndex` property. Make sure that you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly:

```
class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Item2 { get; set; }

    private int _selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set { _selectedIndex = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
...
foreach (DataColumn dc in _loadedData.Columns)
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(new DataItem() { Item1 = dc.ColumnName, Item2 = cbxOptions });
}
```

Then you bind the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ComboBox` in your `DataTemplate` to your `SelectedIndex` property:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Item2}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
          SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"></ComboBox>
```

And change the selected index of a `ComboBox` by setting the source property of the corresponding object in the `Items` collection:

```
(ListBox.Items[2] as DataItem).SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was also hoping to have a two way bind so that the Label Item1 is passed back into the other value in the Dictionary cbxOptions. Basically so that cbxOptions becomes a Dictionary of the combobox options with the associated value of the listbox entry it is currently associated with.